# Python 3 - counting matches in two lists (including duplicates)

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, I'm new to programming and python, I've looked here but can't find a solution, if this is a stupid question though please forgive me!

I have two lists and I'm trying to determine how many times items in the second list appears in the first list.

I have the following solution:

```
    list1 = ['black','red','yellow']
    list2 = ['the','big','black','dog']
    list3 = ['the','black','black','dog']
    p = set(list1)&set(list2)
    print(len(p))
```

It works fine apart from when the second list contains duplicates.

i.e. list1 and list2 above returns 1, but so does list1 and list3, when ideally that should return 2

Can anyone suggest a solution to this? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: I can't understand what you really want to count, could you clarify your question?

Comment: You say ``list1`` and ``list2`` return 1, but they will return 0 as there are no elements that are equal. Check your example.

Comment: Your examples make no sense, `list1` has nothing in common with either of the other lists.

Comment: Yes, i just spotted the error in the example, rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because of you're using [sets](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozensets#set-types-set-frozenset) for your collection type. Sets have two characteristics: they're unordered (which doesn't matter here), and their elements are unique. So you're losing the duplicates in the lists when you convert them to sets, before you even find their intersection:

```
>>> p = ['1', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3']
>>> set(p)
set(['1', '2', '3'])
```

There are several ways you can do what you're looking to do here, but you'll want to start by looking at the list `count` method. I would do something like this:

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>>> results = {}
>>> for i in list1:
        results[i] = list2.count(i) 
>>> results
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 1}
```

This approach creates a dictionary (`results`), and for each element in `list1`, creates a key in `results`, counts the times it occurs in `list2`, and assigns that to the key's value.

*Edit:* As Lattyware points out, that approach solves a slightly different question than the one you asked. A really fundamental solution would look like this

```
>>> words = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black']
>>> list1 = ['the', 'black', 'dog']
>>> list2 = ['the', 'blue', 'blue', 'dog']
>>> results1 = 0
>>> results2 = 0
>>> for w in words:
        results1 += list1.count(w)
        results2 += list2.count(w)

>>> results1
1
>>> results2
2
```

This works in a similar way to my first suggestion: it iterates through each word in your main list (here I use `words`), adds the number of times it appears in `list1` to the counter `results1`, and `list2` to `results2`.

If you need more information than just the number of duplicates, you'll want to use a dictionary or, even better, the specialized `Counter` type in the `collections` modules. Counter is built to make everything I did in the examples above easy.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> results3 = Counter()
>>> for w in words:
        results3[w] = list2.count(w)

>>> results3
Counter({'blue': 2, 'black': 0, 'yellow': 0, 'red': 0})
>>> sum(results3.values())
2
```

Comment: It might be more appropriate to produce a ``collections.Counter`` object here for ``results``, which could then be iterated over with ``results.elements()``, nicely to provide the equivalent of ``p`` in the question, or summed with ``sum(results)`` as an equivalent to ``len(p)``.

Comment: Yes, now that I've finished my coffee I see that I slightly misread the question. I'll amend it.

Answer (score 9):

Shouldn't list 1 and list 2 return 0?  Or did you mean

```
list1 = ['black', 'red', 'yellow']
```

What you want, I think, is

```
print(len([w for w in list2 if w in list1]))
```

The trouble with using sets is that a set have no duplicates.  In fact, the usual reason for using a set is to eliminate duplicates.  That's just what you don't want here, of course.

Comment: You should make a set from ``list1`` before the list comprehension, as membership tests on a list are very slow. I would also argue the statement *'the usual reason for using a set is to eliminate duplicates'* is bad phrasing - it's a use, but the usual reason for a set is it's the right data structure for the job.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone was wondering how to get matches or the length of the matches from one or more lists. you can do this as well.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [2,4,5]
```

To get matches in two lists, say a and b will be

```
d = [value for value in a if value in b] # 2,3
```

For the three lists, will be

```
d = [value for value in a if value in b and value in c] # 2
len(d) # to get the number of matches
```

also, if you need to handle duplicates. it will be a matter of converting the list to a set beforehand e.g

```
a  = set(a) # and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you'd like to count the frequency of elements of list1 in list2, maybe this solution can work for you:

```
list1 = ['black', 'red', 'yellow']
list2 = ['the', 'big', 'black', 'dog']
list3 = ['the', 'black', 'black', 'dog']
```

first of all we can count the frequency of elements in `list2` and construct a dict, and then we can construct a subdict from the dict according to the `list1`,and to get the total frequency you may count the values of sub_dct:

```
# count the frequency of elements of list1 in list2
def cntFrequency(lst1,lst2):
    dct=dict(Counter(lst2))
    sub_dct={k:dct.get(k,0) for k in lst1}
    return sub_dct
```

and the result is like:

```
from collections import Counter

cnt_dct=cntFrequency(list1,list2)
print cnt_dct
print sum(cnt_dct.values())

# Output
{'black': 1, 'yellow': 0, 'red': 0}
1
```